# MSVC compiler (cl.exe) starts new console window. how to prevent?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, cl.exe

One of my Win10 desktops has very odd problem with visual c++ compiler (vc142 toolchain/msvs2019, Win10): it opens new console window each time when c++ compiler (cl.exe) is started by any GUI app.

as the compiler is in the use by IDEs (e.g. VisualStudio, CLion, QtCreator etc) , it's very useless because output of the compiling can't be caught by callee (IDE) and IDEs don't show any compilation output , especially compile message in case of error. Obviously these IDEs do this indirectly , via build systems like msbuild or cmake . anyway , the problem is there.

So NMake or MSBuild can't be used correctly , because those ones run cl.exe in separate window. I have to run a build procedure from command line manually to see the error message.

the same toolchain can be used correctly on other Win10 hosts. I don't see the difference...

any idea why it 's happening and how to fix?

P.S. probably this is not a problem of cl but some windows terminal settings... or even security issues (I'm not an admin on that host)

Comment: Wild guess, but could there be another `cl.exe` in your `PATH` which is not the correct compiler?

Comment: I'll check this , but all works fine , except that in separate terminal

Comment: just checked - only set of cl compilers for different targets , all ones from VS2019 toochain

Comment: I suggest you can add the following code to hide the console window `#pragma comment( linker, "/subsystem:\"windows\" /entry:\"mainCRTStartup\"" )`

Comment: could you explain the reason of this ? if you eman that I have to add this to my project which I compile in IDEs , this is a shared library , there is no main entry point. are you sure that understood my question - this is not about my sample app which starts in new console window (because it's a library)  but about the compiler itself which perform its work in own console

Comment: @amigo421  Did you ever resolve this?   We're experiencing the same problem

Comment: oh,  it was long time ago 
as I remember that was permissioning issue. it was an office desktop and Program Files folder was restricted somehow, MSVS was installed there but seems didn't have all required permissions, so I've re-installed MSVS into custom folder where I was an owner and problem gone

Comment: @amigo421 Thanks for the tip.  I'm guessing it's a permission/spyware issue as well, but changing install directories didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

For us, it was a corporate spyware program, BeyondTrust/PowerBroker for windows that was somehow making cl.exe misbehave.

PowerBroker basically takes over the UAC control and forces apps to run in privileged mode or non-privileged mode, etc.    I'm not sure the mechanism but somehow it interfered with cl.exe writing to stderr, or ninja.exe's ability to redirect stderr to itself, or ninjas ability to pipe it somewhere or something.

Anyways, putting a whitelist rule in (or killing the beyondtrust service) made VSCode calling cmake calling ninja calling cl.exe behave properly.

EDIT:  More details: **cmake.exe**, **ninja.exe**, and **cmd.exe** are the processes that need to get exempted from BeyondTrust's PRIVMAN to make cmake builds from VSCode function without popups.

Comment: PowerBroker for Windows is a privilege elevation tool used in removing persistent Admin access on user accounts, it's not a spyware tool. The rules used in its execution (and that of the later versions called Endpoint Privilege Management) are defined by your organisation, ideally to help you keep productive in your role without needing to give your account admin permissions. Most problems occur when the tool is used to try and restrict an admin user rather than enable a standard user account.