# Visual Studio CMake build output not going to output window

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2019

I have a project that builds fine on Linux, using CMake to generate either makefiles or ninja build scripts. I'm trying to build that same project on Windows in Visual Studio 2019. Configuration completes successfully as far as I can see, but the build fails. The problem is that I don't know why. Both the configuration and build stages open console windows that automatically close on completion, whether that completion is a success or a failure.

I have tried the recommended "Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->General->Show Output window when build starts", but that makes no difference whatsoever. The "Build" option does appear in the output dropdown, but it contains nothing in the output or Error List panes. I've enabled CMake logging in the options, but those log files only contain very simple 1 line messages about thread execution. Nowhere does the build output get captured.

[image: screenshot of spawned windows]

How do I capture the build output that seems to spawn off into pop-up console windows? I cannot tell what is failing in the build without that information.

I think I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61458198/msvc-compiler-cl-exe-starts-new-console-window-how-to-prevent). Basically, corporate protection software is interfering between CMake and Visual Studio. An answer probably involves insulating VS from that interference somehow.

Comment: This is weird. I have used Visual Studio + CMake at work since 2008 and I have not seen that behavior ever. Can you show a picture of your screen?

Comment: I added a screenshot. These windows close quickly.